# Can I write a function using DataKinds that returns a value of type encoded by the parameter?

Tags: haskell, types, data-kinds

Let's say I have a Currency type:

```
data Currency = USD | EUR | YEN
```

and a Money type that stores an int, and is parameterized by a given Currency (Currency is promoted to a kind with the DataKinds extension).

```
data Money :: Currency -> * where
    Money :: Int -> Money c
```

Is it possible to write a function, `moneyOf`, that takes as its parameter, a Currency value, and returns a Money value which is parameterized by the corresponding type of the Currency value? Such as `moneyOf :: Currency -> Money c`, but we get a compile time guarantee that `c` is the type generated from the Currency value?

Comment: Without dependent types, it seems unlikely. You could have at most `moneyOf :: Proxy c -> Money c`, to be called as `moneyOf (Proxy :: Proxy USD)`, as far as I know.

Comment: The usual approach (without dependant types) is to create a singleton for `Currency`: `data SCurrency (c :: Currency) where SUSD :: SCurrency USD; SEUR :: SCurrency EUR; SYEN :: SCurrency Yen` and write the function `SCurrency c -> Money c`. In this case, since you don't need to know anything about the type of currency (since it is a phantom type) you can get away with just using Proxy.

Comment: I assume you want `moneyOf` to be `Currency -> Int -> Money c` right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, but there are workarounds.  As you saw, the type you'd need to write is something like `moneyOf :: (c :: Currency) -> Int -> Money c`, where `c` is bound both in the type *and* in the function implementation itself (`moneyOf _ amt = Money amt`).  This isn't something we can do in Haskell.  So what can we do instead?  There are two options, depending on how much you really want.

**Option 1: Proxies.**  Define a poly-kinded type

```
data Proxy (t :: k) = Proxy
```

The idea behind this type is that you can use `Proxy :: Proxy t` as a way of passing around a reified term-level representation of the type t.  So, for instance, we can define:

```
moneyOf :: Proxy c -> Int -> Money c
moneyOf _ = Money
```

Then, we can call it like `moneyOf (Proxy :: Proxy USD) 10` to get `Money 10 :: Money USD`.  A trick you can use is to instead give the function the type `proxy k -> Int -> Money c` instead (note the lowercase `proxy`!), so that `proxy` will unify with arbitrary function types.¹  This is great for passing arguments to functions in order to fix their return types, but it doesn't really let you do anything beyond that.

**As you've described your problem, I think proxies are probably the best fit for solving it.**  (Assuming that plain type signatures, like `Money 10 :: Money USD`, don't work, that is – those are even simpler when you can use them!)

**Option 2: Singleton types.**  However, if you find that you need more generality (or if you're just curious), then another approach is to create a *singleton type* like the following:

```
data SingCurrency (c :: Currency) where
  SUSD :: SingCurrency USD
  SEUR :: SingCurrency EUR
  SYEN :: SingCurrency YEN
```

This is called a "singleton type" because each `SingCurrency c` has only one member (*e.g.*, `SUSD` is the unique value of type `SingCurrency USD`).  Now, you can write

```
moneyOf :: SingCurrency c -> Int -> Money c
moneyOf _ = Money
```

Here, `moneyOf SUSD 10` evaluates to `Money 10 :: Money USD`.  But this alone doesn't buy you anything beyond using (except a bit less typing).  Singletons get particularly fun when you want to produce them:

```
class SingCurrencyI (c :: Currency) where
  sing :: SingCurrency c

instance SingCurrencyI USD where scur = SUSD
instance SingCurrencyI EUR where scur = SEUR
instance SingCurrencyI YEN where scur = SYEN
```

Now, if you have a `SingCurrencyI c` constraint, you can automatically *produce* the corresponding `SingCurrency c` value with `sing`, thus allowing you to move from the type level to the term level.  (Note that, although all `Currency`s are instances of `SingCurrencyI`, you need to specify the constraint explicitly if you want it.²)  I can't think of any good examples of using this off the top of my head; I think my suggestion would be to **use singletons only if you find yourself in a situation where you realize you can't accomplish what you need, and realize that the extra type-value synchronization of singletons would help you** (and where you can't redesign yourself out of the situation).

If you do find yourself using singletons, the machinery is all set up for you [in the `singletons` package](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~eir/packages/singletons/README.html), in more generality: there's [a data family `Sing :: k -> *`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-1.1/docs/Data-Singletons.html#t:sing) that takes the place of `SingCurrency`; and there's have [a type class `SingI :: k -> Constraint`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-1.1/docs/Data-Singletons.html#t:SingI) that takes the place of `SingCurrencyI`, which has the single member [`sing :: SingI a => Sing a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-1.1/docs/Data-Singletons.html#v:sing).  There's also [a function `withSingI :: Sing n -> (SingI n => r) -> r`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-1.1/docs/Data-Singletons.html#v:withSingI) which allows you to convert freely from `Sing n` into `SingI n` (the other direction is just `sing`).  (These are all provided in [`Data.Singletons`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-1.1/docs/Data-Singletons.html).)  There's also some Template Haskell in [`Data.Singletons.TH`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-1.1/docs/Data-Singletons-TH.html) that allows you to write

```
singletons [d|data Currency = USD | EUR | YEN|]
```

at the top level of your program in order to define the `Currency` type along with the appropriate `Sing` and `SingI` instances.  (You need the following language extensions enabled, too: `KindSignatures`, `DataKinds`, `TypeFamilies`, `GADTs` or `ExistentialQuantification`, `ScopedTypeVariables`, and `TemplateHaskell`.)

This is really powerful – it's almost like dependent types, if you squint – but it can be a massive pain to use.  Indeed, if you want more information, there's a paper talking about exactly that: ["Hasochism: The Pleasure and Pain of Dependently Typed Haskell Programming"](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/pub/hasochism.pdf), by Sam Lindley and [Conor McBride](https://stackoverflow.com/users/828361/pigworker).  It's definitely readable by anybody who's thinking about these ideas already, although the material is sort of intrinsically tricky; be warned that their notation is slightly different, though.  I don't, unfortunately, know of any good blogpost or tutorial-style introductions to this stuff.

---

¹ I'm uncertain about the status of that type unification rule with type families, though….

² Otherwise, the run-time dictionary containing `sing` won't be passed in, so the value wouldn't be available at run-time.

Comment: Re Option 1, you can use `Proxy#` from `GHC.Prim` to get absolutely no runtime cost of passing the type information.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to option 2 of Antal S-Z's answer is the following.

You keep the `Currency` singletons `SingCurrency`.

```
data SingCurrency (c :: Currency) where
    SEUR :: SingCurrency EUR
    SUSD :: SingCurrency USD
    SYEN :: SingCurrency YEN
```

But instead of using a singleton instance class (`SingCurrencyI`) you can use an existential GADT.

```
data AnyCurrency where
    AnyCurrency :: SingCurrency sc -> AnyCurrency
```

with an auxiliary function that takes the place of the `SingCurrencyI` instances.

```
anyCurrency :: Currency -> AnyCurrency
anyCurrency EUR = AnyCurrency SEUR
anyCurrency USD = AnyCurrency SUSD
anyCurrency YEN = AnyCurrency SYEN
```

Using

```
money :: SingCurrency c -> Int -> Money c
money = const Money
```

and an existential `Money`

```
data AnyMoney where
    AnyMoney :: Money c -> AnyMoney
```

you can implement

```
moneyOf :: Currency -> Int -> AnyMoney
moneyOf c v = case anyCurrency c of
                AnyCurrency sc -> AnyMoney $ money sc v
```

Pattern matching on `AnyMoney` will let you use functions taking an argument of type `Money c`, i.e.

```
useMoney :: Money c -> IO ()
useMoney = undefined
```

will finally get you

```
useUseMoney :: Currency -> Int -> IO ()
useUseMoney c v = case moneyOf c v of
                    AnyMoney m -> useMoney m
```

Comment: Existentials and the type class are a bit orthogonal, but you're right – existentials can come in handy with this sort of thing.

Comment: I prefer existentials *iff* I get the `Currency` from runtime, i.e. a config file.